# How to acces the value of an ArrayList of another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have one class with an arrayList, and i create a method (getList) that will return its value.

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

public void Tes2(){
    data.add("aku");
    data.add("sudah");
    data.add("mandi");

}

public ArrayList getList(){
    return data;
}
```

then i have another class that will call the arrayList from the previous class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tes2 ambil = new Tes2();
    ambil.getList();
    System.out.println(ambil.getList()+" ");
}
```

but when i compile the code, there's nothing is printed. i don't know what is wrong, it's like my arraylist is empty. how can i do it right?

Comment: You've got a "pseudo" constructor. Get rid of the `void`

Comment: e.g., change `public void Tes2(){` to `public Tes2(){`

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the void in the constructor or change it to some other name (eg Loadlist)  so that it becomes a method.  Then from your main class you can call ambit.Loadlist() to load the list and then you can write ambil.getList ()